# nginx config does not get second domain on same server correctly

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

Setup: Ubuntu 18.04 Nginx Apache Varnish PHP Server
Nginx handles the traffic in the first place.

I have two domains pointing to the same server. 
The first Domain works correct, the second one only redirects to the first one.

What is wrong with my configs?

First config which works fine
(Here the nginx works as an reverse proxy for the varnish and Apache.)

```
upstream varnish {
    server 127.0.0.1:6081;
}

upstream apache {
    server 127.0.0.1:8080;
}


server {
    if ($host = domain1.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name domain1.com;
    include inc/acme-challenge.conf;

    location / {
        return 301 https://domain1.com$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    #client_max_body_size    120M;
    server_name domain1.com;

    location /wp-content/uploads {
        alias /var/www/website/wp-content/uploads;
        include inc/gzip.conf;
        include inc/browser-cache.conf;
    }


    error_page 502 /502.html;

    location = /502.html {
       alias /var/www/website/502.html;
    }


    location / {
        proxy_pass          http://varnish;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Port 443;
        proxy_set_header    Host $host;
    }

    location ^~ /phpmyadmin {
        allow 45.77.141.32; #qundg
        allow 87.191.170.222; #qundg

        deny all;
        proxy_pass          http://varnish;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Port 443;
        proxy_set_header    Host $host;
    }

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain1.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain1.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

And here ist the second config (this one does not work)
The Domain should only be managed by the nginx without the Apache or Varnish service.

```
server {

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name domain2.com *.domain2.com;

    root /var/www/domain2.com;
    index index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    server_name domain2.com *.domain2.com;

    root /var/www/domain2.com;
    index index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

Here ist the default config

```
server {
  server_name _;
  listen *:80 default_server deferred;
   error_log /var/log/nginx/default_server_error.log;
  return 444;
}
```

Comment: The symptoms suggest that your second configuration is not being used. Try: `nginx -T` to view the configuration that Nginx is actually reading.

Comment: `nginx -T` shows me both configs @RichardSmith

Answer (score 0):

You're using a wildcard in the second DNS name, that should be something that's not recognized in your certificate.

To get a wildcard you could follow instruction here https://medium.com/@saurabh6790/generate-wildcard-ssl-certificate-using-lets-encrypt-certbot-273e432794d7

I have few case in which I have more than 1 DNS pointing to the same website and for those I created different nginx configuration files, and applied for each che certbot authentication. I noticed that using 3rd level dns (something.mysyte.com) in the same config file brouth certbot to override certificates when I had more than 1.

In your specific case you have 2 dns name in the second configuration and one has a wildcard. If you try to remove the dns with the wildcard and reinstall certificates it should work. You can then setup a new block with each 3rd level domain and get certificate for each one, or follow the guide to get the wildcard certificate.

Comment: i tried it as well without the Wildcard. Problem still exists. I can also disable ssl (port:80) at all and the problem persists.

Comment: is this part in second configuration correct ?  if ($host = **domain1.com**) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

   **server_name domain2.com *.domain2.com;**

Comment: why shouldn't it? @Andrea It just says redirect to ssl if non ssl is incoming.

Comment: My bad, but in this case there's something i don't understand: domain1 (wordpress i think) is reacable from both http and https domain1 and http domain2, while https domain2 lead to a different site, is that the behavior you're looking for?

Comment: domain1 is wordpress, correct. 
domain2 should serve another website on the same server within the folder /var/www/domain2.com

Comment: That's reasonable, but in configuration you posted, the code block for http domain2 has a redirect to https domain1, is it a typo?

Comment: i changed the redirect, but it does not change what happens